# Strange Lower Back Tingling

Tags: squats, pain, lower-back

This may be piriformis syndrome, but according to the [article from squat university](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/squatuniversity.com/2017/11/21/how-to-correctly-treat-piriformis-syndrome/amp/) it’s not, because the twisting motion and hyperextending motion cause the tingling.

Yesterday, I did beltless front squats and towards the end started developing lower back tightness during the sets. I haven’t been doing front squats frequently, but have been doing a lot of back squats so I went decently heavy 6x4 with ~83%. The sensation mostly occurred at the top, and when I tried to stay extra upright.

This morning I woke up with mild tingling in my lower back so I though I must have injured my lower back doing them. I was going to squat again today but decided against it to rest.

The weird part came when I was trying to see how bad the injury was (I know this is stupid) so I loaded the bar with a small amount of weight to see if I could feel it in my back. While I was picking up the bar, *my back actually felt better* than when I was walking around. It actually felt *good* to deadlift, like it was relieving the lower back tingling.

The sensation is mild and I’m quite confident it will clear up soon, but my questions are: What is this? What could cause something like this? And what should I be doing to prevent this from occurring in the future?

Comment: Closing this because it asks for a diagnosis. Tingling, while not painful, is not to be taken lightly, and should be presented to a doctor for analysis. There is no way we can diagnose you over the Internet.

Comment: @Alec That's fair. I'm pretty sure it's inflammation from some muscle in my butt. I was wondering if there were similar experiences here.

Comment: @ColinHicks I have a herniated disc in my neck and my arm tingles from it when I squat sometimes because of the shoulder position. Definitely go see a doctor if this doesn't clear up.

Comment: @E.Aigle Thankfully, it's completely gone (took about 3 days). I think during the front squats, I was hyperextending my lower back in an effort to stay more upright. I think it was because my lower back was still a bit sore from deadlifts, so this was a unconscious effort to reduce loading on the erector muscles.  It's definitely something I should be aware of as overtime it can lead to more serious problems.

Comment: @ColinHicks Oh cool, glad you're feeling better